# std::vector initialization in another function

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, try-catch

I need to initialize vectors and check whether the initialization has been successful many times, so I decided to create a function for that. The problem is that I haven't been able to find a way to tackle this problem without losing a significant amount of efficiency. This has been my attempt so far:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    bool init(std::vector<double>& v, int n, double x) {
        try {
            v = std::vector<double>(n, x);
        }
        catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
            return false;
        }        

        return true;
    }

    int main() {
        int n = -1;
        std::vector<double> v;

        if (not init(v, n, 1)) {
            std::cerr << "Vector failed to initialize" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
```

Notice that I create a new vector and then call the copy constructor, so the cost is similar to initializing two vectors instead of one. Is there an efficient alternative to this?

Comment: Using [`v.resize(n, x);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize)?

Comment: Now you have an `if` for each vector "creation" instead of a try/catch... you haven't saved much, if anything.

Comment: Note that with most operating systems supporting memory overcommit, actually getting `bad_alloc` is rare and maybe not worth trying to handle in your case.

Comment: That is not initialisation. Okay you're initialising a temporary, but the core point is that you are _assigning_ to the original vector, not initialising it, and certainly not "many times".

Comment: The existing answers are good. Just to point out though that, honestly, this is a non-problem: instantiating an empty vector does basically nothing. Profile before mangling your design over hypothetical considerations like this.

Comment: *"Is there an efficient alternative to this?"* - Most efficient alternative would be to check your implementation's `std::vector` default c'tor. Unless you are using something very esoteric, that c'tor doesn't perform any more work than setting 2 pointers to `nullptr`. No allocations at all (which would be the expensive operation).

Comment: A few things wrong  Firstly, `std::vector` accepts `std::size_t` (an unsigned integral type) values to specify sizes - an `int` with value `-1` is converted to the maximum value of a `size_t` - so your code tries to allocate (typically) more memory than can be addressed by your implementation. Second (if `n` is a valid size) the sequence `v.resize(0); v.resize(n, x);` does the same as `v=std::vector<double>(n,x)` (apart from effect on `v`s reserved size). Third, a single `try`/`catch` in `main()` is no less efficient than your function swallowing a locally thrown exception to return a `bool`.

Comment: @KillzoneKid: [Alternative operator representations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative).

Comment: @Peter: _"so your code tries to allocate (typically) more memory than can be addressed by your implementation"_ Wasn't that, like, the whole point?

Comment: @Peter: _"Third, a single try/catch in main() is no less efficient than your function swallowing a locally thrown exception to return a bool"_ Therefore the choice is arbitrary - so where is the "wrong"? Not sure what your point is here.

Comment: I would seriously question whether you actually need to do this. Your init function is more prone to misuse than letting an exception propagate through your code, because client code is not forced to use the boolean return value. On top of that, the "pattern" of default constructing something and then initializing in a function makes code harder to reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - the OP's code exhausts memory, but the OP description says they are trying to efficiently "initialize".   And my third point is that writing a function to swallow an exception and return a bool which can be tested gives no benefit (in terms of "efficiency", in terms of code simplicity, or anything else) than simply doing required operations and having a single `try`/`catch` at the top of the call stack (unless you view potential of forgetting to test the `bool` as a benefit).

Comment: @Peter: It also says that they are checking whether the initialisation has been successful; it makes sense to try a failure case.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that is indeed not initialization. I definitely did not use the right word to say what i meant. I am not "initializing" it many times because this is not the actual code, but just an oversimplified example.

Comment: @Peter I have chosen `n = -1` on purpose to force an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Notice that I create a new vector and then call the copy constructor, so the cost is similar to initializing two vectors instead of one.

I do not think so.

You create an empty `std::vector<double> v`, which is a relatively cheap operation, and then assign it a new value inside `init()`.

However, in `init()` a temporary `std::vector<double>(n, x)` is assigned to `v`, so the move assignment operator, not the copy constructor, will be called and no unnecessary copying is performed.

Comment: It would be cheaper to return the vector or initialize it in place though.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit that's true, bad wording :(

Comment: That answers my question.

Comment: Is it better practice then to explicitly call `std::move`? Also, could you provide a good reference on the assignment operator, please?

Comment: @Just_a_newbie you don't need to use `std::move` here as `std::vector<double>(n, x)` is an rvalue . It means that using `std::move` explicitly is a bad practice. For the start, you might take a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_assignment_operator

Answer (score 2):

You cannot *initialize* something after it has been constructed. However, the simplest "solution" to your "problem" is to construct the vector in place instead of using an "init" function with an "output parameter".

```
int main() {
    int n = -1;
    try
    {
        std::vector<double> v(n, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    catch(const std::bad_alloc&)
    {
        std::cerr << "Vector failed to initialize" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you really need an "init" function for your vector, then return by value and use it to initialize something at the caller side.

```
std::vector<double> init(int n, double x) {
  return std::vector<double>(n, x);
}
```

Both versions leave you with less things to think about. For example, you don't have to instantiate and empty vector first, then check the return value of a function (which you can easily neglect to do) and you don't have to document what happens if a non-empty vector gets passed, or read the documentation if you're the user of the function.

Comment: Emphasis on the scare quotes surrounding "problem" though - the original code was, frankly, fine

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Right, I think I was trying to answer a different question, and not doing a good job of it. This is more of a long comment than an answer.

Comment: Think it's just this side of answerworthy ;)

Comment: @junachopanza The whole point of creating the init function is to avoid having to write a try-catch every time I create a new vector. In your second bit of code, where do you check if there has ocurred any exception?

Comment: @Just_a_newbie The whole point of exceptions is that you don't have to write a try-catch around every piece of code that can throw, but that you decide at which level the exception needs to be handled. It is up to you to figure out which part of code can recover from the exception and continue. And this will not be the same for each instantiation of a vector.